# Twilio serverless function URL, custom domain?

Tags: twilio

So I deployed a serverless app to the beta Twilio function area. It works fine, but I was wondering how/where I could replace the twil.io URL with our company's domain. I can publish a CNAME entry in public DNS, I have a SSL cert to apply, etc. I just don't see where in the Twilio web console I would add the custom domain.

I tried opening a ticket with Twilio support, but since this is a beta area they punted to the engineering team. And I haven't heard back yet...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You can use the [Twilio Serverless Toolkit](https://www.twilio.com/docs/labs/serverless-toolkit) for this when you [deploy a Function](https://www.twilio.com/docs/labs/serverless-toolkit/general-usage#deploy-a-project)!

For example, I have this Twilio Video app. In my `package.json`, [image] the `name` is "tfvideo".

Then when I deploy using `twilio serverless:deploy`, the twil.io URL becomes `tfvideo-1829-dev.twil.io...`[image: deployment details]

because those are the default settings: that command will create a new environment for you with the following properties:[image: deploy default settings]

You can change the environment it deploys to by passing the domain suffix of the environment into the deploy command using the `--environment` flag. [More info here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/labs/serverless-toolkit/deploying).

Let me know if this helps at all!

Comment: Thanks for the reply! This is somewhat helpful, but what I'm looking for is adding a custom domain. For example, let's say vidchat.diamondcellar.com. I manage our company's public DNS, so I can add an CNAME alias that points the twil.io DNS name to vidchat.diamondcellar.com. And I have an SSL cert that I can apply so that https sessions are good. I don't see a place where I can add this custom domain in Twilio. I've done same thing this multiple times on AWS and Azure, but when it comes to Twilio I'm at a loss :(

Comment: There is no CNAME support with Functions at the moment; you’d have to use a proxy service to take care of that like one of my teammates used Cloudflare Workers for an important app for our SIGNAL conference: here's an example too https://github.com/adamchasetaylor/cf-worker-proxy/

Answer (score 3):

> There is no CNAME support with Functions at the moment; you’d have to use a proxy service to take care of that like one of my teammates used Cloudflare Workers for an important app for our SIGNAL conference: here's an example too github.com/adamchasetaylor/cf-worker-proxy – lizziepika 18 mins ago

This is the workaround that should serve our purposes. Thanks lizziepika for the quick assist!